# Drag and Drop Table - moving cells to different columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, drag-and-drop

I am attempting to make a drag and drop table. I was modelling my code after a demo JQuery has on their site, but I can't get mine to work. I also don't know if what I am doing is the best option for me.

I am wanting to move the table cells from one column to another. Is there something I'm missing with my code or is there a better solution for this?

```
<script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#paid, #partially_paid, #owes" ).sortable({
          connectWith: ".tdPayment"
        }).disableSelection();
      });
</script>
```

Table

```
<table class="paymentTable" id="dragTable">
    <tr>
        <th class="thPayment">Paid</th>
        <th class="thPayment">Partially Paid</th>
        <th class="thPayment">Owes</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tdPayment" id="paid">
        <?php
            if ($paid_name == true) {
                echo $paid_name;
            } else {
                echo "No one has paid";
            }
        ?>
        </td>
        <td class="tdPayment" id="partially_paid">
        <?php 
            if ($partially_paid__name == true) {
                echo $partially_paid__name . " - " . $partially_paid_amount;
            } else {
                echo "No one has made a partial payment";
            }
        ?>  
        </td>
        <td class="tdPayment" id="owes">
        <?php
            if ($owes_name == true) {
                echo $owes_name;
            } else {
                echo "Everyone has paid something";
            }
        ?>  
        </td>
    </tr>   
</table>
```

UPDATE WITH ADDED IN DIV

```
<table class="paymentTable" id="dragTable">
        <tr>
            <th class="thPayment">Paid</th>
            <th class="thPayment">Partially Paid</th>
            <th class="thPayment">Owes</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tdPayment" id="paid">
                            <div>
            <?php
                if ($paid_name == true) {
                    echo $paid_name;
                } else {
                    echo "No one has paid";
                }
            ?>
                            </div>
            </td>
            <td class="tdPayment" id="partially_paid">
            <div>
            <?php 
                if ($partially_paid__name == true) {
                    echo $partially_paid__name . " - " . $partially_paid_amount;
                } else {
                    echo "No one has made a partial payment";
                }
            ?>  
            </div>
            </td>
            <td class="tdPayment" id="owes">
            <div>
            <?php
                if ($owes_name == true) {
                    echo $owes_name;
                } else {
                    echo "Everyone has paid something";
                }
            ?>  
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `$("#paid, #partially_paid, #owes" ).sortable({` you're making the their child element to be sortable, so, the result is make the elements in each `td` sortable and can be dragged to each other.
As if you allow `td` to be dragged to other column, then you may have to calculate how many `td`s in each column and add something like `rowspan` to make the table looks not stange(also, you might want `th` to be dragged too), how about create some `div`'s in your each td, and simply drag the `div` to different column?

```js
$(function() {
        $( "#paid, #partially_paid, #owes" ).sortable({
          connectWith: ".tdPayment",
          remove: function(e, ui) {
            var $this = $(this);
            var childs = $this.find('div');
            if (childs.length === 0) {
               $this.text("Nothing");
            }
          },
          receive: function(e, ui) {
            $(this).contents().filter(function() {
                return this.nodeType == 3; //Node.TEXT_NODE
             }).remove();
          },
        }).disableSelection();
      });
```

```css
table {
  border : solid 1px #000;
}

th, td {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

div {
  background-color: #0cc;
   margin: 1px auto;
   width: 50px;
   height: 30px;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<table class="paymentTable" id="dragTable">
    <tr>
        <th class="thPayment">Paid</th>
        <th class="thPayment">Partially Paid</th>
        <th class="thPayment">Owes</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tdPayment" id="paid">
            <div > A </div>
            <div> B </div>
            <div> C </div>
        </td>
        <td class="tdPayment" id="partially_paid">
            <div> D </div>
            <div> E </div>
            <div> F </div>
        </td>
        <td class="tdPayment" id="owes">
            <div> G </div>
            <div> H </div>
            <div> I </div>
        </td>
    </tr>   
</table>
```

Comment: Even when I put a div around my php code this still doesn't work.

Comment: You want to move the whole column, include titles?

Comment: No, I don't want to include titles. The area I wrapped the div's around is the actual data that I want to move.

Comment: So after movement, the source `td` will become empty then?

Comment: I'm really not sure how to structure this. Your answer is what I am looking to do in a sense and it will get me going, but I am doing this with items from my db and if I move all of the table cells out of one column, I need the column to echo my else statement. However, with my code nothing will even move.

Comment: @Becky Edited, please see the `td`'s  behavior after you remove all of the `div`s and move a `div` back to an empty `td`.

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong, but nothing is moving. I have all of the Jquery libraries in the file. Then the JS you posted and the table I last put in my question on here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81876/discussion-between-fuyushimoya-and-becky).